# PHP: Post data with Headers....not working

Tags: php, http-headers

Simple Script

```
<?php
$host = "mysite.com";
$path = "/test.php";
$data = "drivingMeCrazy";
$data = urlencode($data);

header("POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n" );
header("Host: $host\r\n" );
header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\r\n" );
header("Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n" );
header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n" );
header($data);
?>
```

When running this, my server just gives me Internal Error.  All I need to do is just....POST.  Nothing else.  I don't need a response or anything.

Following Specs from here:  http://www.sixapart.com/pronet/docs/trackback_spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer I was looking for here:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/1211-doing-http-post

Curl would have worked.  I just wanted to make this work on a different platform as well, so I wanted to find the most direct way.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The [`header` function](http://php.net/header) is for setting the header for the response. If you want to make a request to another server, try [cURL](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: Thanks for fixing my post.  How do you add code on here though...seriously?  :)  I know there is the code button, but I hate having the blank, invisible spaces I'm suppose to type in between.  Is there a way to use tags like [code] or something? that will format it properly and give you a way to see where you are actually pasting code to.

Comment: @Senica Prefix each line of code with 4 spaces, or use back ticks (the ~ key) to markup `code` inline.  Edit your post and you can see how others have improved the markup.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$process = curl_init($host);                                                                         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $additionalHeaders));  //<-- update to reflect your content-type
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);                                                                           
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); // <-- you probably don't need that                                                
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);                                                                         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                                             
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);                                                            
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);                                                                
$return = curl_exec($process);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `header()` to send data to a 3rd party server.  `header()` simply sends header information to the client making the request to your webserver.

Look into the cURL library for initiating requests to 3rd parties from your server-side PHP:

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

I cannot vouch for this library, but it appears to be a freely available implementation of Trackbacks for PHP:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phptrackback/